# Laravel 5 how to use get parameter from url with controller's sign in method

Tags: laravel, controller, get, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement a login system where the user will be redirect back only if there is a get parameter in the url, else it will be redirect to the profile page.

So, if the uri is something like this (no get parameter)

```
/login
```

if success, the user will be redirect to the profile page.

But if the uri has the get parameter like for example

```
/login?r=articles
```

the user will be redirected to the articles page instead of the default route to the profile page.

Question is, in the controller, how can do this, if possible, or how can I check for the get parameter?

**routes.php**

```
// Signin
Route::post('/account/signin', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',
    'as' => 'user.signin',
]);
```

**UserController.php**

```
// Signin
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'login-email' => 'required|email',
        'login-password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ( Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['login-email'], 'password' => $request['login-password']]) )
    {

        // Tried this, isn't working... (maybe something's missing ??)
            $redirect = $request->input('r');
            if ($redirect) {
                return redirect()->route($redirect);
            }
        // -->

        return redirect()->route('user.account');
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**signin.blade.php**

```
<form role="form" action="{{ route('user.signin') }}" method="post" class="login-form" name="login">

    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('login-email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="login-email" value="{{ Request::old('login-email') }}" placeholder="Email..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('login-password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="login-password" value="{{ Request::old('login-password') }}" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="{{ Request::old('remember') }}" id="remember">
        Remember
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in!</button>

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
</form>
```

Thanks.

***Updated***

Thank you all for your replies, the fact is that I'm still getting to know Laravel and that's probably why I can't implement it right the solutions that you guys shared.

So this said, I got it working by creating a conditional hidden field that holds the query value and this way once the user submits the form, it will be passed with the rest of the $response arguments.

**signin.blade.php**

```
<form role="form" action="{{ route('user.signin') }}" method="post" class="login-form" name="login">

    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('login-email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="login-email" value="{{ Request::old('login-email') }}" placeholder="Email..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('login-password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="login-password" value="{{ Request::old('login-password') }}" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="{{ Request::old('remember') }}" id="remember">
        Remember
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in!</button>

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
    <!-- Verify condition -->
    @if(isset($_GET['referer']))
        <input type="hidden" name="referer" value="{{ $_GET['referer'] }}">
    @endif
</form>
```

***UserController.php***

```
// Signin
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'login-email' => 'required|email',
        'login-password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ( Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['login-email'], 'password' => $request['login-password']]) )
    {

        // Check for the new argument 'referer'
        if (isset($request->referer)) {
            return redirect()->route($request->referer);
        }
        // -->

        return redirect()->route('user.account');
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Like so, it works.

Don't know if it's a viable and secure way to do it in Laravel 5, but it is working.

Comment: sorry @ManashSonowal but I still can't make it work...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When you have an URI such as `login?r=articles`, you can retrieve `articles` like this:

```
request()->r
```

You can also use `request()->has('r')` to determine if it's present in the URI.

And `request()->filled('r')` to find out if it's present in the URI and its value is not empty.

Comment: Thanks @user2094178 that allowed to replace the $_GET var

Comment: Great answer. Thank you

Comment: @user2094178, what if I have 2 or more key to get from URL. For example :
?id=123=?val=test
My problem, if I "request()->id" it'll return "123=?val=test"

Comment: It should be `?id=123&val=test`.

Answer (score 12):

// only query

```
$query_array = $request->query();
```

or

```
$query = $request->query('r');
```

// Without Query String...

```
$url = $request->url();
```

// With Query String...

```
$url = $request->fullUrl();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as I'm using laravel I would like to use Laravel's functiionalities to do that.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Laravel then use their helper which works just out of the box, i.e. if your route or url has a auth middlewere and user is not logged in then it goes to login and in your postSign or inside attempt just

```
 return redirect()->intended('home'); //home is the fallback if no intended url is provide
```

**UserController**

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request){
$this->validate($request, [
    'login-email' => 'required|email',
    'login-password' => 'required'
]);

if ( Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['login-email'], 'password' => $request['login-password']]) )
{

    return redirect()->intended('user.account);
}
return redirect()->back();
```

}

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? what was the error or what is the status so that I can guide you>?

Answer (score 2):

first use this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

then you can get any data from your url

```
$name=Input::get('term', false); //term is the parameter name we get from URL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are still in this quest you can use

> Request

like

```
$request->r
```